# What is the value in @string/action_settings?

Tags: java, android, string

I've accidentally deleted @string/action_settings in the String.xml, and now it's popping up errors. I know where to replace the String, but I don't know what value is for that string. So my question is, what is the value of "action_settings" and what does that do?

Comment: <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>. It's shown when you push menu button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is Settings. It serves to you to compose your layouts. Is created by default on Eclipse.

```
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
```